# Execution flow of React + Node.js application deployed on AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-cloudfront

I am developing a web application in React with a Node.js back-end. I would like to host the images and static files built for the React application on Cloudfront. However, the React application relies on the Node.js server to obtain some changing data to populate the views.

I need to have a thorough understanding of the flow of the application in order to come up with a reasonable design. Here is what I think happens:

1. User enters URL in the browser
2. Client is directed to the closest Cloudfront edge location
3. Cloudfront serves the HTML and images to the browser
4. The React application bootstraps in the browser
5. An API call is made to the Node.js server, which returns the required data
6. The browser renders the React application.

Am I understanding this correctly? Is there a better way to architect my web application?

I am not able to find the information I require online and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your architecture is correct.
Just to be clear, CloudFront is not hosting your files.  CloudFront is a cache and will fetch your files from an Origin, typically an Amazon S3 bucket.

Using React && AWS Amplify, you can create a serverless architecture for this type of setup with minimal work.  You can get started by following the instructions at https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/

In a nutshel :

Install with:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
$ amplify configure
```

Then in your project :

```sh
amplify init 
amplify add api #this will create your API as AWS Lambda functions exposed through Amazon API Gateway)
amplify add hosting #this will create the Amazon S3 bucket for hosting and the cloudfront distribution)
amplify push #to create all this on your AWS account for you
```

If you search for 'aws amplify react' you will easily find a dozen blog posting showing you how to get started.  There are so many I can not recommend one in particular.